# JIRA error: Remote server returned error 407 proxy authentication required

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, jira

I'm trying to access JIRA data (get project) using JIRA REST API. Here is how I'm making it:

```
public enum JiraResource
{
project
}

public class JiraService : IJiraService
{
    #region JiraService member functions
   /* public void DoWork()
    {
    }*/

    private const string str_baseURL = "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9";

    private string str_Username;
    private string str_Password;

    public JiraService(string username,string password)
    {
        str_Username = username;
        str_Password = password;
    }
    public string runQuery(
        JiraResource resource,
        string argument = null,
        string data = null,
        string method = "GET")
    {
        string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/",str_baseURL,resource.ToString());
       // string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", str_baseURL);
        if(argument != null)
        {
            url = string.Format("{0}{1}/",url,argument);
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        if (data != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }
        }
        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; //Getting error here.
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        { result = reader.ReadToEnd(); }

        return result;
    }

    private string GetEncodedCredentials()
    {
    string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", str_Username, str_Password);
    byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }
```

I'm using username and password as admin and admin (I think this is default). Please note that, this url ("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9") showing me json objects from the browser. However, from my code, I'm getting exception "Remote server returned error (407) proxy authentication required ".

As per this post([The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581609/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)) I used useDefaultCredentials="true". But this is not working.

Is there anything that I'm missing? Please guide me.

Comment: Your link loads fine with me, without being logged into JIRA. It appears this link does not require authentication at all. Try removing it from the header

Comment: I just tried your code with authentication, and got a forbidden error. Removing the authentication header, however, works fine.

Comment: Could you please post me code sample here, what is removed? Are you saying commenting this : request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials) ?

Comment: Remove this line: `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);`

Comment: What should be the username and password? still I'm getting same error. Please post your whole code.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, removing the header means you're not sending a username/password. The page you're trying to access is public.

Comment: The URL request( HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;) I have is this : https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9project/  Is this correct?