# Proxy asking for credentials

Tags: c#, webclient, webproxy

This is what I currently have

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
        //proxy.Address = new Uri("http://" + proxyIP.Text + ":" + proxyPort.Text);
        //proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername.Text, proxyPassword.Text);
        proxy.Address = new Uri("http://" + "96.44.147.138" + ":" + "6060");
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername.Text, proxyPassword.Text);
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        client.Proxy = proxy;
        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"));
    }
```

The issue is that, I still get an error saying

> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (407)
>   Proxy Authentication Required.

Even though the information is correct.

Any ideas?

My question is not solved through the other thread because this question involves `using` and the I'm doing it in winform.

Comment: Check if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581609/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: @ArunSelvaKumar I do not believe it's related? I could 100% wrong. This is in winforms

Comment: You are still using system.net to make the call to the other server. You could try putting the config setting proposed in the other question in your app.config file.

Comment: @MartinBrown Umm... Where would my app.config file be?

Comment: Put it in the same location as your project file. Add it to your project and call it app.config. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13043569/20553

Comment: @MartinBrown I'm honestly retarded. I looked for a solid amount on it online and I can't figure it out =/ It's a winforms project