# "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required." Error when registering deployment group in Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the powershell script generated by Azure Devops to config my deployment group. How do I fix this.

"The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

Comment: Ohhhh K!?, that error is specific and not really a PowerShell issue, but an environmental one. So, off-topic for SO.  Tak to your network folks to see what that proxy server expects. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve it?

Comment: The issue was something to do with how the network engineers setup the environment.

Comment: Do you mean the issue has been solved? May I know the solution?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're behind an authenticating proxy. Powershell isn't great at handling them - some PS commands use the system proxy, some don't. There's several ways of working around it though if you search for that specific issue.

You could try this added to your script (just insert at the start of the script), which takes your current credential/proxy and passes it to the any web requests:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()

[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of messages are not unique to anything with Azure. It's purely an environmental network issue, that you must implement in your code.

Similar posts have been asked here...

[The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581609/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)

... but they actually showed what their code looks like when making a request ...

```
myProxy.Credentials = NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <bypasslist>
            <clear />
        </bypasslist>
        <proxy proxyaddress="myproxy:9000"
               usesystemdefault="false"
               bypassonlocal="true"
               autoDetect="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

... whereas you are not. I point you back to the SO rules in my comment.

So, see that SO, to determine if anything in that thread helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the powershell script, you can find it calls `.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup ...`.
So, you can edit it to specify proxy information:

`./config.cmd --proxyurl xxx --proxyusername "myuser" --proxypassword "mypass" --deploymentgroup ...`

More information: [Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)