# SSIS - Proxy Authentication Required SQL Server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

We have a SQL Server 2019 cluster where we have one primary node(n1) and one secondary node(n2).

When I run a SSIS job with a proxy account, it fails on the node(n1) and I get an error:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

When I failover and then the primary node(n1) become secondary and the secondary one(n2) become the primary and I run the same job, I no longer have the proxy error and the job runs successfully of the node (n2)!

Do you have an idea why this error happens, and how to fix it? Because it's a strange issue we are facing right now!

Comment: Which task in SSIS throws this? 407 looks like a web error code.

Comment: The task is to open an api connection but the problem only occurs with the default cluster setting but when i fail over, i have no error and the job runs succesfully

Comment: Is that all the SSIS packages does - open an API connection? Does the SSIS package do other secured activities? Do they work? This is another piece of the puzzle

Comment: Is the same package. For testing purposes, it only open an API connection for now. The question is, how the package runs successfuly on the second node but not on the first node ?!

Comment: There must be a config difference. Note that a SQL Agent Proxy account and a Web proxy (that's throwing the error) are completely different things. If you run it under the normal SQL Agent account, do you get the same error? If not, perhaps the SQL Agent proxy credential is not authorised to use the web proxy in that particular node. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581609/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required